# Rails + Sunspot: Multiple model search, but only certain fields on one of the models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, full-text-search, sunspot

In my Rails app I'm using Sunspot to index a few different models. I then have a global search form which returns mixed results. This is working fine:

```
Sunspot.search(Person, EmailAddress, PhoneNumber, PhysicalAddress) do
  fulltext params[:q]
  paginate :per_page => 10
end
```

I would like to add an additional model, say Project, to this search. The Project model has quite a bit that is indexed:

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  searchable do
    string :category do
      category.name.downcase if category = self.category
    end

    string :client do
      client.name.downcase if client = self.client
    end

    string :status

    text :tracking_number
    text :description

    integer :category_id, :references => Category
    integer :client_id, :references => Client
    integer :tag_ids, :multiple => true, :references => Tag

    time :created_at, :trie => true
    time :updated_at, :trie => true
    time :received_at, :trie => true
    time :completed_at, :trie => true
  end
end
```

How can I modify my original `Sunspot.search` call to add searching for Project records by just the `tracking_number` field and *not* the `description` field?

Answer (score 4):

```
Sunspot.search(Person, EmailAddress, PhoneNumber, PhysicalAddress, Project) do
  fulltext params[:q] do
    fields(:tracking_number, :other_fields_outside_your_project_model)
  end

  paginate :per_page => 10
end
```

This will do full text search on tracking_number field and any other fields you specify, particularly in your Person, EmailAddress, PhoneNumber, and PhysicalAddress models.

Comment: but how than display it in view?

Comment: The search will return a list of matching records possibly of different types. You can display an attribute or the returned value of a method on a record after calling respond_to? on that record's attribute/method.

Comment: you should post a new question for this.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to define your tracking_number as a text field and not a string field. Full text search only on "text fields".

Did you try this :

```
text:tracking_number
```

And your sunspot search looks like :

```
Sunspot.search(Person, EmailAddress, PhoneNumber, PhysicalAddress, Project) do
  fulltext params[:q]
  paginate :per_page => 10
end
```

See you

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes, I should probably use the `text` method instead. However, I was meaning for the question to focus on how to limit my search to only one field of a given model when doing a multiple-model search. I'll update the question to be more precise.

Comment: I made an other answer/solution

Comment: but how than display it in view?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try something like :

```
Sunspot.search(Post) do
  keywords 'great pizza', :fields => [:title, :body]
end
```

You can make one request for each model and then concat your results in only one list. I think you can't make it on one search.

Comment: Thanks again for the reply. I suppose this could work, but it seems it would break any pagination and sorting, etc. of all the results. Is there a way around this?

Comment: Using will_paginate you can make a pagination of your concataned array. I think it's not a problem.

Comment: also breaks score-based automatic ordering